# read text file with extended ascii from Google Cloud Storage (Java)

Tags: java, google

We have a text file with extended ascii (words like 'Systèmes' and 'Café').
It is in Google Cloud Storage.  Its Content-Type is text/csv.  If I download it via the browser UI (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/...) all of the characters are correct.  However, If I download it from java, using the code below, I get crap for each of the extended ascii characters.

```
    Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
    String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
    List lines = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(fileContent.split("\\r?\\n")));
```

The file is, I believe, UTF-8 encoded.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Engineering. We only support [good](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions. [Many sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) have [different rules](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067). Feel free to take your issue to an appropriate site if one exists. Search existing answers first. Edit your question to fit the sites needs. Please [don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) by failing to delete your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh - the problem was not with GCS at all.  Instead of:

```
String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
```

I need to use:

```
String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601